# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Third Party Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core

I am looking for a bit of direction here. I am building an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web interface to an existing jira tool that does some queries and presents status. For authentication, my calls to the server that retrieve data need proper jira credentials to operate. However, the API I am using never establishes a connection via logging directly into jira. It opens a connection in the code with the passed credentials.

So my question is, what is the proper way to do this in ASP.NET Core 3.1? I don't need someone to do all the work for me, just point me in the right direction. in WPF, I simply had the user enter their name and password and I established the connection object at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [these docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/). The user shouldn't be putting in their Jira creds in your app.

**OAuth 2.0 (3LO) for apps**

- The app directs the user to an Atlassian screen that prompts them to
  grant access to their data on the Atlassian site. The screen displays
  the access being requested in the Atlassian product.
- The user grants (or denies) access to their data on the Atlassian
  site, via the screen.
- The user is directed back to the external service. If the user
  granted access, the external service can now access data (within the
  specified scopes) from the Atlassian site on the user's behalf.

[image]

Comment: Never mind on previous comment, I see the C# sdk I am using has an OAuth route as well. Thank you, will look into this.